# IIS 0x80070020 error

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to start up a web app with visual studio, and I keep getting the error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020).

I did some digging and i found that port 80 was used by the actual System proccess(lol) so i changed the default web site port from IIs manager to something that is not used by anything. I am still getting the error though.

One thing to note is that I can fire up a new website project but not a web application.

Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: can you configure the process to use a port other than 80? that is the default HTTP port...

Comment: Did you save the project before running the code?  I think the error message has something to do with reading the configuration files and not the com port.  The error message says FILE so I' not sure from the info you posted if the error has anything to do with the port.

Comment: I tried to configure it for other ports, nothing happened. Also, i saved it yes, as the complete error message includes the file.

Comment: Execute `net stop http` at command prompt.

Comment: unfortunately this did not fix it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

some application (check Skype connection port setting) can block ports

or use console:

netstat -aon | find «:80»
netstat -aon | find «:443»